# AVL Tree implementation with nodes or without nodes

Tags: c++, nodes, avl-tree

We have a class project to implement an AVL tree.
Here are two very general implementations:

```
template<class T>
class AVLTree {
  int key;
  int height;
  int BF;
  T data;
  AVLTree<T>* father, leftSon, rightSon;
.
.
.
}
```

A friend told me I really should use Nodes but he wasn't able to explain why.
So here is the second implementation which I have seen in many places (using Node):

```
template<class T>
class AVLTree {
  int key;
  int height;
  int BF;
  T data;
  Node* father, leftSon, rightSon;

  class Node {
    int key;
    int height;
    int BF;
    T data;
    Node* father, leftSon, rightSon;
  }
.
.
.
}
```

What's really the difference? Is my implementation impossible in terms of the  compiler?

Comment: In the second version, you should not have three Node* variables in the AVLTree - just one (for the root node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you are right and nodes are not necessary, though remember C++ is an OOP language, and the object you want is an AVLTree, which is consisted of nodes.